# Webview did not returning after call payment app

Tags: android

I'm using webview fullscreen mode in android, but in a determinate point my application open an app (payment app) and then return an url saying approved or repproved, however, this returning url do not open in my webview, it's opening in browser. How do I do to open this url in my webview? And time what open payment app, the fullscreen mode is disabled. Can someone help me? 
This is part of code about my application call payment app:

```
@Override

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Webview view, String url){
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().startsWith("myurl")){   
        return false;  
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));  
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
    return true;

}
```